# Downloading Attachment and Marking Mail as Unseen

Tags: python, email, imap

I want to download the attachments from Unread Messages, but also does not want the messages to be flagged **Seen**.

The below code works, but currently setting the mail as **Seen**

Tried `'(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])'` , but then even mail download stopped.

```
import upload,checkFileAtServer,sha1sum,email, getpass, imaplib, os
detach_dir = '.'
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login('myaccount@gmail.com','password')
m.select("inbox")

resp, items = m.search(None, "(UNSEEN)")
items = items[0].split()

for emailid in items:
  #resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, '(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])')
  resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
  email_body = data[0][1]
  mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)
  temp = m.store(emailid,'+FLAGS', '\\Seen')
  m.expunge()

  if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
    continue

  print "["+mail["From"]+"] :" + mail["Subject"]

  for part in mail.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue
    if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
        continue

    filename = part.get_filename()
    att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)

    if not os.path.isfile(att_path) :
        fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
        fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        fp.close()
        sha1sum = sha1sum.calculateSHA1(att_path)
        print type(sha1sum)
        responseFromServer = checkFileAtServer.responseFromServer(sha1sum)
        if(responseFromServer == "NOT_CHECKED"):
            upload.uploadToSecureServer('root','root',att_path,att_path)
```

Anybody can guide me what am I missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: `BODY.PEEK[]` will download the entire email if that's what you want.

Comment: @Max : I just want to download the attachments.

Comment: First you need to find where they are, possibly by downloading `BODYSTRUCTURE`.  Then you can do `BODY.PEEK[section]`, where section is like 1.1 or 1.3.2 or whatever.  Also, you're storing `+FLAGS \Seen` which will of course mark the message seen....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to mark a message as `\Seen`, don't call the `STORE` IMAP command and don't use `FETCH`able items which are documented to cause an implicit marking as such (yes, the `RFC822` is an alias for `BODY[]` which causes the message to be marked as read).